# Не запускается программа на Python

Tags: python

Установил версию Питона 3.7.2 , после чего зашел в саблайм, написал просто `print("hello")` и зашел в командную строку. Там пишу путь к файлу `"C:/Python37/test/first.py"` и после того, как я нажимаю <kbd>Enter</kbd>, у меня просто открывается саблайм с моим кодом, а сам код в командной строке не выполняется.

Что делать, помогите пожалуйста))

Comment: `python C:\Python37\test\first.py`

Comment: Прилагайте код к вопросу.

Comment: Для того, чтобы пользоваться выполнением скрипта внутри sublime text вы должны настроить так называемую build system во вкладке build. Подробнее про настройку build system посмотрите здесь: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/build_systems.html#basic_example

Comment: Хороший гайд: https://techcave.ru/posts/103-nastroika-sublime-text-dlja-python.html

Comment: у вас формат `.py` ассоциирован с редактором, поэтому и открывается файл. Если сделаете ассоциацию с `python.exe`, то при двойном клике файл выполнится интерпретатором

Answer (score 1):

В Windows может быть какому-то расширению присоединенная программа, которая каждый файл с этим расширением автоматически запускает.

У вас к расширению `.py` присоединена программа *Sublime Text*. Потому или явно напишите программу (python), с которой хотите этот файл запускать

```
python "C:/Python37/test/first.py"
```

или измените программу присоединенную к расширению `.py` на `python.exe` - см. например [7 способов восстановления ассоциации файлов в Windows](https://vellisa.ru/default-file-type-associations-restore). После этого вы будете мочь выполнить ваш код так, как вы написали в вашем вопросе:

```
"C:/Python37/test/first.py"
```

или - так как в вашем пути нет пробелов

```
C:/Python37/test/first.py
```